# Calling a method on class instead on an object

Tags: python-3.x

This is about method dict.fromkeys():

> The method can be used only directly on dict class and not on a specific dictionary object. Therefore this method will be always written as dict.fromkeys()

Why is this implemented like this? Why you don't call dict.fromkeys() on dictionary object but on dict class?

Comment: `Class().method()`

Answer (score 4):

Because it makes sense.
From its own docstring:

> Returns a new dict with keys from iterable and values equal to value

It won't make sense to create a new (empty?) dictionary just to be able to call a method that returns a new dictionary anyway.

```
dict().fromkeys(list_of_keys, value)  # works but does it make any sense?
#   ^^ creating a new, empty dictionary and immediately throwing it away
```